# LINQ GroupBy, finding Max from Count (and then some...)

Tags: c#, linq

I've been trying to figure this one out for quite a while...

I'm trying to query license usage for my company.  I have a service that captures the data and a SQL server DB to store it.  My issue is querying the data.  I thought it would be the easiest part, but not so much.

1. The data is captured every five minutes with the time of capture recorded.
2. The maximum value needs to be of a specific capture point, but within a specific time range (60 minutes)
3. The data needs to be grouped by specific fields.
4. Users can select an application, feature, and/or division, and the start and end times for the query.

**Sample Data**

```
+-------------+---------+----------+------------------+
| Application | Feature | Division |   RecordedTime   |
+-------------+---------+----------+------------------+
| App1        | Feat1   | Div1     | 2014-01-01 00:00 |
| App1        | Feat1   | Div1     | 2014-01-01 00:00 |
| App1        | Feat1   | Div1     | 2014-01-01 00:00 |
| App1        | Feat1   | Div1     | 2014-01-01 00:00 |
| App1        | Feat1   | Div2     | 2014-01-01 00:00 |
| App1        | Feat1   | Div1     | 2014-01-01 00:05 |
| App1        | Feat1   | Div2     | 2014-01-01 00:05 |
| App1        | Feat1   | Div2     | 2014-01-01 00:05 |
| App1        | Feat2   | Div2     | 2014-01-01 00:10 |
+-------------+---------+----------+------------------+
```

The result should be

```
Time: 2014-01-01 00:00
+------+-------+------+---+
| App1 | Feat1 | Div1 | 4 |
| App1 | Feat1 | Div2 | 2 |
| App1 | Feat2 | Div2 | 1 |
+------+-------+------+---+
```

Here is the code I have so far:  (Some is cobbled from other posts on Stack Overflow)

```
var results = context.ViewData
    .Where(x => (x.FeatureID == 1) && 
           StartTimeInput <= x.RecordedDateTime &&
           EndTimeInput >= x.RecordedDateTime)
    .GroupBy(x => new
        {
            Application = x.ApplicationName,
            Feature = x.FeatureName,
            Division = x.Division,
            RecordedDateTime = x.RecordedDateTime
        })
    .Select(x => new
        {
            Application = x.Key.Application,
            Feature = x.Key.Feature,
            Division = x.Key.Division,
            RecordedDateTime = x.Key.RecordedDateTime,
            Count = x.Count()
        })
    .OrderBy(x => x.RecordedDateTime)
    .AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x =>
        {
            var stamp = x.RecordedDateTime;
            stamp = stamp.AddMinutes(-(stamp.Minute % 60));
            return stamp;
        }).Select(x => new
        {
            Stamp = x.Key,
            Data = x .Select(y => new
            {
                Application = y.Application,
                Feature = y.Feature,
                Division = y.Division,
                Count = y.Count
           })
        });
```

The above code gets me closer, but it doesn't provide me with a **maximum** value per hour by application, feature, and division.

## UPDATE

To clarify, the trouble I'm having is finding the maximum value of a count at a specific point in time, over a range of 60 minutes, by group.

Grouping by RecordedTime, Application, Feature, Division on the sample data would give me this result:

```
+------+-------+------+---+------------------+
| App1 | Feat1 | Div1 | 4 | 2014-01-01 00:00 |
| App1 | Feat1 | Div2 | 1 | 2014-01-01 00:00 |
| App1 | Feat1 | Div1 | 1 | 2014-01-01 00:05 |
| App1 | Feat1 | Div2 | 2 | 2014-01-01 00:05 |
| App1 | Feat2 | Div2 | 1 | 2014-01-01 00:10 |
+------+-------+------+---+------------------+

Between the time range 2014-01-01 00:00 and 2014-01-01 01:00, 
the marked lines should be selected as the maximum value for that time range 
if you assume that between that time range, none of the grouping exceed that value:

   +------+-------+------+---+------------------+
-->| App1 | Feat1 | Div1 | 4 | 2014-01-01 00:00 |<--
   | App1 | Feat1 | Div2 | 1 | 2014-01-01 00:00 |
   | App1 | Feat1 | Div1 | 1 | 2014-01-01 00:05 |
-->| App1 | Feat1 | Div2 | 2 | 2014-01-01 00:05 |<--
-->| App1 | Feat2 | Div2 | 1 | 2014-01-01 00:10 |<--
   +------+-------+------+---+------------------+
```

If the sample data were something like this:

```
+-------------+---------+----------+------------------+
| Application | Feature | Division |   RecordedTime   |
+-------------+---------+----------+------------------+
| App1        | Feat1   | Div1     | 2014-01-01 00:00 |
| App1        | Feat1   | Div1     | 2014-01-01 00:00 |
| App1        | Feat1   | Div1     | 2014-01-01 00:00 |
| App1        | Feat1   | Div1     | 2014-01-01 00:00 |
| App1        | Feat1   | Div2     | 2014-01-01 00:00 |
| App1        | Feat1   | Div1     | 2014-01-01 00:05 |
| App1        | Feat1   | Div2     | 2014-01-01 00:05 |
| App1        | Feat1   | Div2     | 2014-01-01 00:05 |
| App1        | Feat2   | Div2     | 2014-01-01 00:10 |
.......................................................
| App1        | Feat1   | Div1     | 2014-01-01 00:40 |
| App1        | Feat1   | Div1     | 2014-01-01 00:40 |
| App1        | Feat1   | Div1     | 2014-01-01 00:40 |
| App1        | Feat1   | Div1     | 2014-01-01 00:40 |
| App1        | Feat1   | Div1     | 2014-01-01 00:40 |
| App1        | Feat1   | Div1     | 2014-01-01 00:40 |
| App1        | Feat1   | Div1     | 2014-01-01 00:40 |
| App1        | Feat2   | Div2     | 2014-01-01 00:40 |
| App1        | Feat2   | Div2     | 2014-01-01 00:40 |
| App1        | Feat2   | Div2     | 2014-01-01 00:40 |
| App1        | Feat2   | Div2     | 2014-01-01 00:40 |
| App1        | Feat2   | Div2     | 2014-01-01 00:40 |
+-------------+---------+----------+------------------+

The grouping and results would look like this:

   +------+-------+------+---+------------------+
   | App1 | Feat1 | Div1 | 4 | 2014-01-01 00:00 |
   | App1 | Feat1 | Div2 | 1 | 2014-01-01 00:00 |
   | App1 | Feat1 | Div1 | 1 | 2014-01-01 00:05 |
   | App1 | Feat1 | Div2 | 2 | 2014-01-01 00:05 |
-->| App1 | Feat2 | Div2 | 1 | 2014-01-01 00:10 |<--
-->| App1 | Feat1 | Div1 | 7 | 2014-01-01 00:40 |<--
-->| App1 | Feat2 | Div2 | 5 | 2014-01-01 00:40 |<--
   +------+-------+------+---+------------------+
```

The difference is, in the 60 minutes between 00:00 and 01:00 on 2014-01-01, three more people from Division 1 began using Feature 1 of Application 1 at 00:40, so the maximum number of licenses in use between 00:00 and 01:00 for Feature 1 of Application 1 became seven.  The same logic applies to Feature 2 and Division 2 with the maximum value becoming five.

Hope this helps!  This is why I've been struggling with this for so long, it isn't even an easy problem to explain.

Comment: I think your example is wrong....you have 9 rows, but your result set only has 7 (4+2+1)

Comment: @Aducci - I'm looking for the maximum, not the sum.

Comment: First group by Application, Feature and Division. Then group those by RecordedDateTime. Order the subgroups by count descending and take the first one.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. First, define what is maximum value. Secondly, if by maximum value, you mean count, maximum value per hour by application for "App1, Feat1, Div1" is 5, not 4(60-minute rule)?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a single query. Let me know if you prefer method syntax and I can translate it for you.

```
var query =   from x in context.ViewData
              where x.FeatureID == 1
              where StartTimeInput <= x.RecordedDateTime
              where EndTimeInput >= x.RecordedDateTime
              group x by new { x.ApplicationName, x.FeatureName, x.Division } into x
              select new
              {
                Application = x.Key.ApplicationName,
                Feature = x.Key.FeatureName,
                Division = x.Key.Division,
                Max = (from g in x
                      group g by g.RecordedDateTime into g
                      orderby g.Count() descending
                      select g.Count()).FirstOrDefault()
              };
```

If you want the time as well, move the subquery into a `let` like this:

```
...
let max = (from g in x
           group g by g.RecordedDateTime into g
           orderby g.Count() descending
           select g).FirstOrDefault()
select new
{
  ...
  Max = max.Count(),
  DateTime = max.Key
};
```